# Formulário não funciona com laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-collective

Fala galera seguinte estou com um problema no envio de formulário nesse [site](http://agenciafront.com.br/apstudents/) 
não estou conseguindo enviar da um erro que não sei o que é segue parte dos meus códigos com o `log` de erro:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use Mail;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function contactPost(Request $request) {
        //$data = $request->only('name', 'email', 'phone');
        //$data['messageLines'] = explode("\n", $request->get('message'));
        $data = $request->all();

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
            $message->subject('Novo Contato: '.$data['name'])
                ->to('felipe@agenciafront.com.br')
                //->to('info@apstudents.com.au')
                ->bcc('danillo@agenciafront.com.br')
                ->replyTo($data['email']);
        });

        return back()->withSuccess("Sua mensagem foi enviada.");
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::post('contact',[
    'as' => 'contact',
    'middleware' => ['lang', 'web'],
    'uses' => 'HomeController@contactPost'
]);
```

Form:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    @if (session('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('success') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {!! trans('contact.text') !!}

                    {!! Form::open(['url' => route('contact'), 'id' => 'contact-form', 'class' => 'uk-form']) !!}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {!! Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.name'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('birthday', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.birthday'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('country', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.country'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('marital', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.marital'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('phone', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.phone'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::email('email', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.email'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}                            
                                {!! Form::textarea('previous_qualifications', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.previous_qualifications'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}                            
                                {!! Form::textarea('which_work', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.which_work'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}                            
                                {!! Form::text('courses', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.courses'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}                            
                                {!! Form::text('how_long', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.how_long'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}                            
                                {!! Form::text('wich_city', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.wich_city'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}                            
                                {!! Form::text('visa', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.visa'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                 {!! Form::text('given_names', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.given_names'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!} 

                                <label for="passport">{!! trans('contact.passport') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::select('passport', [
                                    'Não' => trans('contact.include-children-option-no'),
                                    'Sim' => trans('contact.include-children-option-yes')
                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('where_is', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.where_is'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!} 

                                <label for="kids">{!! trans('contact.kids') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::select('kids', [
                                    'Não' => trans('contact.include-kids-option-no'),
                                    'Sim' => trans('contact.include-kids-option-yes')
                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                <label for="married">{!! trans('contact.married') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::select('married', [
                                    'Não' => trans('contact.include-married-option-no'),
                                    'Sim' => trans('contact.include-married-option-yes')
                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                <label for="english">{!! trans('contact.english') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::select('english', [
                                    'Básico' => trans('contact.include-english-option-ba'),
                                    'Intermediário' => trans('contact.include-english-option-in')
                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                <label for="exams">{!! trans('contact.exams') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::select('exams', [
                                    'Não' => trans('contact.include-exams-option-no'),
                                    'Sim' => trans('contact.include-exams-option-yes')
                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                <label for="considered">{!! trans('contact.considered') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::text('considered_text', null, ['placeholder' => trans('contact.considered_text'), 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                <label for="intentions">{!! trans('contact.intentions') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::select('intentions', [
                                    'estudo' => trans('contact.include-intentions-option-study'),
                                    'migração' => trans('contact.include-intentions-option-migration')
                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                <label for="know">{!! trans('contact.know') !!}</label>
                                {!! Form::select('know', [
                                    'Brasil' => 'Facebook',
                                    'Google' => 'Google',
                                    'Indicação' => trans('contact.include-children-option-indication'),
                                    'Outro' => trans('contact.include-children-option-other')
                                ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                                {!! Form::submit(trans('contact.send'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary send-button']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}

                </div>
```

emails.contato:

```
<ul>
    <li>Nome: <strong>{{ $name }}</strong></li>
    <li>Nascimento: <strong>{{ $birthday }}</strong></li>
    <li>País de nascimento: <strong>{{ $country }}</strong></li>
    <li>Estado Civil: <strong>{{ $marital }}</strong></li>
    <li>Telefone: <strong>{{ $phone }}</strong></li>
    <li>Email: <strong>{{ $email }}</strong></li>
    <li>Qualificações anteriores: <strong>{{ $previous_qualifications }}</strong></li>
    <li>Experiência de trabalho relevante: <strong>{{ $which_work }}</strong></li>
    <li>Cursos de escolha e período: <strong>{{ $courses }}</strong></li>
    <li>Quanto tempo você pretende ficar na Austrália: <strong>{{ $how_long }}</strong></li>
    <li>Em que cidade você gostaria de viver? porque?: <strong>{{ $wich_city }}</strong></li>
    <li>Quando você gostaria de aplicar para o visto?: <strong>{{ $visa }}</strong></li>
    <li>Nomes dados: <strong>{{ $given_names }}</strong></li>
    <li>Tem passaporte de mais algum outro país, sem ser o brasileiro?: <strong>{{ $passport }}</strong></li>
    <li>De onde é?: <strong>{{ $where_is }}</strong></li>
    <li>Tem filhos?: <strong>{{ $kids }}</strong></li>
    <li>Se você é casado e tem filhos, você pretende incluí-los na sua aplicação?: <strong>{{ $married }}</strong></li>
    <li>Nível de inglês: <strong>{{ $english }}</strong></li>
    <li>Você já fez algum exame de inglês?: <strong>{{ $exams }}</strong></li>
    <li>É considerado na Austrália? Se sim, explique porque um e o resultado: <strong>{{ $considered }}</strong></li>
    <li>Quais são suas intenções na Austrália?: <strong>{{ $intentions }}</strong></li>
    <li>Como você soube sobre nós?: <strong>{{ $know }}</strong></li>
</ul>
```

LOG com os 3 últimos erros:

```
#97 /home/front/public_html/apstudentslaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#98 /home/front/public_html/apstudents/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#99 {main}
```

OBS: O erro ocorre quando você preenche o formulário e envia.

Comment: Aonde exatamente ele dá esse erro? esse log não traz uma informação clara

Comment: Assim que você preenche o form e envia ele da erro

Comment: Coloque o erro que é apresentando no `debug` do *Laravel*. por favor